# Where to find documentation for iOS 6 Core Bluetooth

Tags: ios, xcode, core-bluetooth

In iOS 6, new core bluetooth classes such as CBPeripheralManager and CBMutableCharacteristic were introduced.  However, I've looked at [core bluetooth documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295) and can't find any documentation on the new classes.  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way, in my opinion, is to just look at the header files in Xcode.  Assuming you've added `CoreBluetooth.framework`, just expand that, then `Headers`, in Xcode.  The headers inside are all documented in the same way as Apple's Class References online.

To make it even easier, I personally decided to download [Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/), which can compile HTML/PDF/etc. documentation straight from those header files.  If you go about it that way, the headers are stored at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreBluetooth.framework/Headers`.

Comment: Thanks -- it's better than nothing.  Anyone know WHEN Apple will complete the core bluetooth documentation, and give us an official Programming Guide?  The WWDC 2012 video is excellant, but it's not comprehensive, like Apple's other dev prog guides.

Comment: Assuming you have access to the iOS 7 beta, they have recently added an official programming guide in the Pre-Release Developer Library.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a paid developer, take a look at 2012 WWDC sessions videos:

Core Bluetooth101: session 703

Advanced Core Bluetooth: session 705

You can find the videos and PPT slides at:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/

The slides reference your classes above.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you can find some further information here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/navigation/#section=Frameworks&topic=CoreBluetooth

Answer (score 0):

Does not these solve your purpose :

[Developer.Apple.Com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CoreBluetooth_Framework/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011295)

[Geppy Parziale](http://geppyparziale.com/post/39709522801/invasivecode-core-bluetooth-for-ios-6-core)

Comment: The first link I already posted.  And I also said it didn't help me.

Comment: Then there is no such till now :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no documentation for now.
 
All you can do is check the header files. Hopefully, you can check the iOS 5.1 to 6.0 API Differences (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/iOS60APIDiffs/index.html) and look for the changes of the `CoreBluetooth.framework`).